# Manuscripts section in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing

I need to separate manuscripts from other bibliography (printed) and want to have a reference for each manuscript with the indication of the Library (to which it belongs: Biblioteca Nacional de Portugal, British Library, Bayerische Staatsbibliothek ...) as well as its shelf-mark.

Desired output should be like the following example:

> Castel-Branco, António de (1588). Liber tertius in Astronomiam praxeos
> sphaerae utriusque et planae et solidae, quarum illam astrolabon, hanc
> globum vocant astronomicum [Manuscript]. Biblioteca Pública de Évora,
> cod. CXXV I-2-3.

I know there is a package by M. Rouquette intended to describe manuscripts. But is there a way to do it with Biblatex only? The following is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Unpublished{Castel-Brancobpe1588,
  author    = {Castel-Branco, António de},
  title     = {Liber terTius in Astronomiam praxeos sphaerae utriusque et planae et solidae, quarum illam astrolabon, hanc globum vocant astronomicum},
  year      = {1588},
  keywords  = {manuscripta},
  library   = {Biblioteca Pública de Évora},
  shelfmark = {CXXVI-2-3},
}
@Unpublished{Castel-Branco1587,
  author    = {Castel-Branco, António de},
  title     = {Commẽtarij in 8\textsuperscript{o} libros Phisicorum Aristotelis traditi in academia Eborensi sub praeceptore Ant\textsuperscript{o} de Castel Branco anno Domini. 1587\textsuperscript{o}},
  year      = {1587},
  keywords  = {manuscripta},
  library   = {Biblioteca Nacional de Portugal},
  shelfmark = {6283},
}
@Book{ThorndikeLynn1949TSoS,
  author    = {Thorndike, Lynn and Sacro Bosco, Joannes de and Robertus and Scot, Michael and Cecco},
  title     = {The Sphere of Sacrobosco and its commentators},
  year      = {1949},
  language  = {lat;eng},
  series    = {Corpus of mediaeval scientific texts ; v. 2},
  publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
  address   = {Chicago},
}
@Book{hoffmann1987handwoerterbuch,
  title        = {Handwörterbuch des deutschen Aberglaubens. Band 1: Aal - Butzemann},
  year         = {1987},
  editor       = {Bächtold-Stäubli, H. and Hoffmann-Krayer, E.},
  publisher    = {Walter de Gruyter},
  address      = {New York, Berlin},
  ignoreisbn   = {9783110065893},
  ignoreseries = {Handwörterbücher Zur Deutschen Volkskunde Series},
  ignoreurl    = {https://archive.org/details/handworterbuchdesdeutschenaberglaubensband3},
  keywords     = {mitologia (Alemanha) -- folclore (Alemanha) -- secundaria},
}
@Book{BerggrenPtol00,
  author    = {J. Lennart Berggren and Alexander Jones},
  title     = {Ptolemy's geography: and annotated translation of the theoretical chapters},
  year      = {2000},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  address   = {Princeton and Oxford},
  keywords  = {secundaria},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[keyword={manuscripta},title={Manuscritos}]
\nocite{Castel-Branco1615} \nocite{Castel-Brancobpe1588} \nocite{Castel-Branco1587}

\printbibliography[keyword={secundaria},title={Bibliografia}]
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You question isn't quite clear. Are you asking: How should I set up my `bib` entry to output a bibliography entry for a manuscript? If so, it might help to add what output you'd like to see.

Comment: Like this: Castel-Branco, António de (1588). Liber tertius in Astronomiam praxeos sphaerae utriusque et planae et solidae, quarum illam astrolabon, hanc globum vocant astronomicum [Manuscript]. Biblioteca Pública de Évora, cod. CXXVI-2-3.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to define your custom entry type by defining a custom driver. The following example shows how to do this.

- Create a `.dbx` file to define the custom field `shelfmark` to make it available in your custom entry type `manuscript`.
- Declare the field formats for `title` and `shelfmark` as they should be used in `manuscript` entries.
- Declare a driver that defines which fields to print and which punctuation to use.

Finally you need to add the option `datamodel=manuscript` when loading the `biblatex` package to tell it that it also should use it.

You can then define the manuscripts in your `.bib` file as `@manuscript` entries. Other entry types should remain unaffected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear, 
    doi=false, 
    url=false, 
    isbn=false, 
    datamodel=manuscript
]{biblatex}

% \DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\begin{filecontents*}{manuscript.dbx}
    \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{manuscript}
    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{shelfmark}
    \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[manuscript]{shelfmark}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareFieldFormat[manuscript]{title}{#1 [Manuscript]}
\DeclareFieldFormat[manuscript]{shelfmark}{cod.\ #1}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{manuscript}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{title}%
    \newunit\newblock    
    \printfield{library}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}
    \printfield{shelfmark}%
    \finentry}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@manuscript{Castel-Brancobpe1588,
  author    = {Castel-Branco, António de},
  title     = {Liber tertius in Astronomiam praxeos sphaerae utriusque et planae et solidae, quarum illam astrolabon, hanc globum vocant astronomicum},
  year      = {1588},
  keywords  = {manuscripta},
  library   = {Biblioteca Pública de Évora},
  shelfmark = {CXXVI-2-3},
}
@book{BerggrenPtol00,
  author    = {J. Lennart Berggren and Alexander Jones},
  title     = {Ptolemy's geography: and annotated translation of the theoretical chapters},
  year      = {2000},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  address   = {Princeton and Oxford},
  keywords  = {secundaria},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[keyword={manuscripta}, title={Manuscritos}]
\nocite{Castel-Brancobpe1588}

\printbibliography[keyword={secundaria}, title={Bibliografia}]
\nocite{BerggrenPtol00}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Since I am not familiar with drivers, where should I put the dbx file? Within the tex file (as you did) or in the same directory as the tex file?

Comment: The way I placed the code in the tex file will just generate a dtx file in the same directory. You will see that after compilation there will be a new file in the directory with exactly the same contents. So it’s essentially up to you.

Comment: Second thoughts: I think I will put the manuscripts into a separate file and then call the different files with \addbibresource. When I put the code in my file Latex (lualatex) keeps complaining with the following error : File `manuscript.dbx' already exists on the system.

Comment: This should be only a warning, but not an error. The code will write the file every time you compile it. If the file is already existing, there will be this warning. It should not affect the output. Apart from that, you may spread your bibliography over as many files as you wish. Just include all of them with one call of `\addbibresource` for each.